# Data Analysis -Video Games data set

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

I have a dataset of video games which has sales across 4 different regions JAPAN_Sales,NA_Sales,EUR_Sales,IND_Sales and Global_Sales. Sales are from the Year 1980 to 2016.
I want to visualize the sum of Global_Sales from the Year 2000 to 2010. I am not able to do. I am a beginner in Pandas.
I have tried the below code but stuck after that:

```
vg.groupby('Year').sum()
```

The column names are :

```
'Rank',
 'Name',
 'Platform',
 'Year',
 'Genre',
 'Publisher',
 'NA_Sales',
 'EUR_Sales',
 'JAP_Sales',
 'IND_Sales',
 'Global_Sales']
```

Comment: `vg.loc[(vg['Year'] >= 2000) & (vg['Year'] <= 2010), 'Global_Sales'].sum()`

Answer (score 0):

Your technique correctly sums per year, but it also attempts to sum genres and publishers etc.

- We can limit the `groupby` to a single series that interests you, `Global_Sales`
- Once that’s done, we get a series indexed on years, so we can use [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) with the years you want
- sum again to get the total:

```
vg.groupby('Year')['Global_Sales'].sum().loc[2000:2010].sum()
```

---

Alternately get the sum of values directly

```
vg.loc[vg['Year'].between(2000, 2010), 'Global_Sales'].sum()
```

Comment: i am not getting the total sales from 2000 to 2010. I am only getting sales from 2000 to 2010 i.e. each year total sales. What i want is a single number which shows the total sales.

Comment: @PythonLearner simply add a `.sum()` − I’ve edited the answer.

Comment: Why sum() is there 2 times. Can i simply put the sum() method at the end once?.Please help me understand the logic behind it.

Comment: Once you’re getting the totals (i.e. sums) per year, then restricting the number of years, the getting the sum of the selected years. You can probably use a single sum too.

Comment: Using a single sum() is giving an error, i tried it.

Comment: You didn’t share your data @PythonLearner so I can only keep guessing and never test what I’m proposing. Also please add your error into the question [with the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: @Cimbsali. If you can guide me as to how to upload the dataset on stackoverflow that would be great. I am not able to upload the dataset on StackOverflow

Comment: @PythonLearner just put the output of `print(df.head())` or `print(df.sample(10))` in a code block − we definitely don’t need the whole dataset.

Comment: By the way @PythonLearner I tried with this second answer with the dataframe from your other question and it works